# Late Binding Errror in VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I am getting a late binding error when I try to change one of the values in my ArrayList of Structs. It comes when I try to change the Distance value in the SetDistance() member. Please tell me how I can change this value successfully. Thanks a lot.

```
Public Class ClientClass
    Private Structure Client
        Public Address As String
        Public Distance As Double
    End Structure

    Private ClientList As ArrayList 

    Public Sub New()
        ClientList = New ArrayList
    End Sub

    Public Sub Add(Address As String)
        Dim NewClient As Client
        NewClient.Address = Address
        NewClient.Distance = 0.0
        ClientList.Add(NewClient)
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetDistance(Address As String, Distance As Double)
        Dim Index As Integer = GetIndexOf(Address)
        If Index <> -1 Then ClientList(Index).Distance = Distance 'ERROR
    End Sub

    Public Function GetIndexOf(Address As String) As Integer
        If ClientList.Count = 0 Then Return -1
        Dim Index As Integer
        For Index = 0 To ClientList.Count - 1
            If ClientList(Index).Address = Address Then Return Index
        Next
        Return -1
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is that you're using an `ArrayList`. Don't. They have been obsolete since .NET 2.0 and the introduction of the `List(Of T)` class.  If you want a collection of `Client` values then use a `List(Of Client)`. The `Item` property will then return a `Client` value instead of an `Object` reference.  The `Object` class has no `Distance` property, hence the late-binding issue.

That will just highlight another issue though.  This will not work:

```
ClientList(Index).Distance = Distance
```

even if `ClientList` is a `List(Of Client)`.  That's because `Client` is a value type and thus `ClientList(Index)` will return a COPY of the value in the collection, not the actual value.  That code would modify the copy and then immediately discard it, thus doing nothing useful while appearing to do so. For that reason, it's not even allowed.  What you would need to do is get the copy, assign it to a variable, make the change and then push the copy back into the collection:

```
Dim client = ClientList(Index)
client.Distance = Distance
ClientList(Index) = client
```

The thing is, if you're allowing properties to be edited then you really ought to be using a class rather than a structure anyway.  You don't have to follow this rule but it's good practice to make structures immutable, i.e. unable to be modified once created.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Your code worked perfectly.